# What does the trigger for Glasses With A Number On Top actually mean?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2018

The description of the *Glasses With A Number On Top* says

> post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year's begin that gets starred

### But what does this mean?

±12 hours could mean *around 12 hours* or it could mean *12 hours before and after*.

> - **Does the trigger mean around 12 hours *before* the UTC New Year?**
> - **Does the trigger mean around 12 hours *after* the UTC New Year?**
> - **Does the trigger mean 12 hours *before or after* the UTC New Year?**

#### It could mean any of these!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

± is being used here with one of its [generally acceptable meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign) as that of an [engineering tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance#Mechanical_component_tolerance)

So we're talking within 12 hours either way of midnight UTC of New Year's day so as to allow everyone around the world a shot at getting the hat.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "within" specifies a time range (not a specific moment). Here, the activity needs to happen within a range of 12 hours, (ahead or lagging time-zone).

Completing the required activity, at any time, falling into the range of the given time, will be awarded the hat.